# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code

Tags: php, angularjs, http

I have some trouble with folowing structure. I have 2 domains: `example.com` and `api.example.com`. I wrote main site in `example.com` on Angular. I use this code in `example.com/app.js` to call function in `api.example.com`:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://api.example.com/register',
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {
        email: register.data.email,
        password: register.data.password
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    }
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    }, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
});
```

And all ofthis gives me errors

```
OPTIONS http://api.example.com/register 400 (Bad Request)
```

and

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.example.com/register. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400
```

My php code returns folowing

```
//some logic code here
if ( $json['status'] == 0 )
{
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET'); 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');  
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($json['data']);
}
else
{
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
    header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    http_response_code(400);
}
```

Where my `$json['status']=0` everything is OK. It works, return status 200 OK. When I give wrong parameters, I have `$json['status']=1` and I get an error which I described.

Full header which network returns

```
Request URL:http://api.example.com/user/register
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Remote Address:78.46.140.200:80
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:close
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 09 Mar 2017 17:12:22 GMT
Server:Apache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,az;q=0.2
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:api.example.com
Origin:http://example.com
Referer:http://example.com/register
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Could you provided the http call data that the ajax method produces? Both the OPTIONS and POST call please.

Comment: @Pheagey I wrote in post my ajax query. I don't make calls with OPTIONS method. When my php file return error 400 header he gives me this error. I send data to php always with POST method

Comment: `preflight` is the OPTIONS request. Open the network tab in a browsers and run the code. You should see the .ajax method will automatically make an OPTIONS request before POSTing due to the request being a cross origin request (CORS) type call.

Comment: In general I will make some switch case to return other headers too (for example 404 or 405). Now problem in this headers. When I wrote some other header I get same mistake for example `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.example.com/register. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404`

Comment: @Pheagey yes, look `Request URL:http://api.example.com/register
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Remote Address:XX.XX.XX.XX:80`

Comment: And he don't make any other post requests if php returns error

Comment: Ok, that is what I needed to know. the OPTIONS request is return a 400.
Now we need to move onto looking at the header and/or body syntax. Are you able to provide the raw request headers / body?

Comment: I will add full header to the post. Response returns everything that I print after line `http_response_code(400);`

Comment: In your php you need to check if the request type is Options and respond to that appropiately.

Comment: @yBrodsky I tried to make this, but again, script things that method is OPTIONS only if he make second part of code (if json status is not equal to 0)

Comment: No, you should handle the options request even before that IF you have there. Options will come before whatever you are trying to send. That's why you have to be BEFORE the if. Otherwise you will always fall to the else and it will not work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a fact, all problem was in Angular. At first Angular send OPTIONS request, only then if this request has 200 OK header send selected request (in my case POST). I just made 200 OK header for all OPTIONS methods.